# How to pass data between two Github workflows (JS custom action)

Tags: github-actions

I am building a custom action and the action can perform multiple operations depending on the parameters passed to it.

So in 1st workflow, it can be called as

```
with:
   DO: create
```

This will return a site_id which can be used to perform any other jobs in a different job file.

```
with: 
   DO: delete
   SITE_ID: {{ want to send previous SITE_ID }}
```

So the question is how do I share data b/w these two workflows executed one after another.

Answer (score 1):

The output from your Action will need to be added as a job output as described in [GitHub Docs: Defining outputs for jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs)

If your second job is already dependent on the first job, you are likely using the `needs` keyword already. Then you can use the output from the first job fairly easily by referencing the given output.

```
jobs:
  create:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      SITE_ID: ${{ steps.action-create.outputs.SITE_ID }}
    steps:
      - id: action-create
        uses: your-action@main
        with:
          DO: create
  delete:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: create
    steps:
      - uses: your-action@main
        with:
          DO:      delete
          SITE_ID: ${{ needs.create.outputs.SITE_ID }}
```